# My fiancee's visa extension

Tags: visas, india, afghan-citizens

My fiancee lives in US since 4 years ago and she is still an Afghan passport holder. She applied for an Indian visa and bought her tickets but she wants to stay more then one month in India.

She got the visa on 04/30/2019 for three months but she is planning to come on June  15 so she can stay only one and half month in India. Can she apply again and extend her visa for one more month before coming to India because her return to US ticket date is August 15?